# How to use property for a class that are not derived from object

Tags: python, properties

I have a <strike>django Model class (PS: Model class is a class which represents a database table in django structure. They all derived from `Model` class)</strike> class. Assume that I set its attributes as follows:

```python
class SomeModel(SomeClass):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 23
        self.y = 100

    def z(self):
        return self.x + self.y
```

In my situation, I do not want to handle `z` as a method and call is as `SomeModel().z()` but as an attribute and call it as `SomeModel().z`. Also that attribute should not be updated or changed. In that case I define it as a `@property`

```python
class SomeModel(SomeClass):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 23
        self.y = 100

    @property
    def z(self):
        return self.x + self.y

    @z.setter
    def z(self, val):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

Now, I can use `SomeModel().z` just as an attribute of that class. But since it was not derived from `object`, `@z.setter` fails to work and I can set value to `z` with

```python
some = SomeModel()
some.z
>> 123
some.z = 567
some.z
>> 567
```

Is there a way to use `@property` for classes that are not derived from `object`? Or is there another solution which will allow me to handle my class methods as attributes. My basic need is just handle them as attributes, but it would be better if I can override `set` and `delete` methods too.

**UPDATE:** I realized `Model` class is derived from `object` and I can use `@property` as expected. So Related examples are not valid and I change them some. But my question is still valid since I also have some classes which are not derived from `object`.

Comment: Without the `object` base class when you `obj.x = 5` it will replace the property with `5`.  You can however use multiple inheritance with object and get setattr to work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use new class style in a subclass of an old class, one way to do it would be simply subclass Object as well.

```
class OldNonObjectClass:
    a, b = 2, 3

    @property
    def c(self):
        return self.b + self.a


class SubClass(OldNonObjectClass, object):
    x, y = 4, 5

    @property
    def z(self):
        return self.x + self.y

a = OldNonObjectClass()
print(a.c) 
#5
a.c = 2 
print(a.c)
#2 

b = SubClass()
print(b.z) 
#5
b.z = 2 
# AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple inheritance to make it inherit from `object` too: `class Subclass(ParentClass, object):`

I never tried it for properties, but it makes `super()` work so I guess it answers your question.

If you don't want to use it, you could also implement `__getattr__`.